# Issues executing a ADO Macro from new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to execute a macro from a new worksheet with a button so that it runs in another worksheet (named "ARF Export").

Unfortunately I don't know how to set the worksheet I want the macro to run in to ("ARF Export"). Please could you advise me on how to proceed?

The error I get when I run this code in a different sheet is:

Error 3265 Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal in procedure export_data

When I step into Debug I don't get an error until the end but it skips through my For Loop on line 38 next i

```
for x = 2 To nextrow
        DatabaseData.AddNew
        For i = 1 To 35
            DatabaseData(Cells(1, i).Value) = Worksheets("ARF Export").Cells(x, i).Value
            Next i
        DatabaseData.Update
    Next x
```

All code below---

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDatatoAccess()
    Dim DatabaseConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim DatabaseData As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Pathway
    Dim x As Long, i As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long


    On Error GoTo errorhandler:

    Pathway = Worksheets("ARF Export").Range("AR2").Value
    nextrow = Worksheets("ARF Export").Range("As2").Value


    Set DatabaseConn = New ADODB.Connection

    If Worksheets("ARF Export").Range("A2").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "ARF form is not present for Upload"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    DatabaseConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Pathway

    Set DatabaseData = New ADODB.Recordset

DatabaseData.Open Source:="ARFs", _
    ActiveConnection:=DatabaseConn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
    LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdTable

For x = 2 To nextrow
    DatabaseData.AddNew
    For i = 1 To 35
        DatabaseData(Cells(1, i).Value) = Worksheets("ARF Export").Cells(x, i).Value
        Next i
        DatabaseData.Update
    Next x

    DatabaseData.Close
    DatabaseConn.Close

    Set DatabaseData = Nothing
    Set DatabaseConn = Nothing

MsgBox "The ARF is now uploaded"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("ARF Export").Cells.Range("AK2").Value = Worksheets("ARF Export").Cells.Range("AK4").Value

Worksheets("ARF Export").Cells.Range("AK5").Value = Worksheets("ARF Export").Cells.Range("AK4").Value + 1

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub
errorhandler:

    Set DatabaseData = Nothing
    Set DatabaseConn = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. In your code you are referencing **ARF Export**, so don't get the issue. Is your code throwing an error? if so, what's the error? If not, are you saying that code is not working off **ARF Export** sheet? please clarify

Comment: @Zac The error it gives is - Error 3265 Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal in procedure export_data

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @zac Hi it actually skips through my For Loop and then I get an error at the end through the msgbox

Comment: @zac Apologies for phrasing the question as I did. Thank you for you patience

Comment: You have 2 `FOR` loops. I suspect that you are talking about the one that references `nextrow`. What is the value of `nextrow` when you get to that `FOR` loop?. Also, can you step through the process and identify which line throws the error to `errorhandler`?

Comment: the error occurs in line 38 - next i. The value of next row is 13 and this varies based on the number of rows with data

Comment: This bit of code `DatabaseData(Cells(1, i).Value)` - `Cells(1,i)` is referencing the activesheet rather than any specific sheet.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank you i tried - DatabaseData(Worksheets("ARF Export").Cells(1, i).Value) - and it worked a treat :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help

-Turns out I needed to reference `DatabaseData(Cells(1, i).Value)` once i did this

```
For x = 2 To nextrow
    DatabaseData.AddNew
    For i = 1 To 35
        DatabaseData(Worksheets("ARF Export").Cells(1, i).Value) = Worksheets("ARF Export").Cells(x, i).Value
        Next i
        DatabaseData.Update
    Next x
```

It worked great. Thank you for your help all!